# 2D model simulating water breaking a floodbank

Tags: java, casting

For a homework assignment we have to write a class that simulates water breaking a floodbank (very simplistic 2D simulation).

My implementation works fine but I found that there were many downcasts (in my opinion, a flaw in Greenfoot's API, which should be using generic functions rather than functions that take classes as arguments, but I'm not sure if this is possible in Java since this is the first time I'm writing Java code).

`Sandstone` and `Sand` both derive from `Actor`, which is from Greenfoot.

```
import greenfoot.*;

public class Water extends Actor {
    public Water() {
        getImage().scale(64, 64);
    }

    public void act() {
        if (((DoorbraakWorld)getWorld()).stopped) return;

        if (Math.random() < 0.9) return;

        int dx = 0, dy = 0;
        switch ((int)(3.0 * Math.random())) {
            case 0: dx = 0; dy = 1; break;
            case 1: dx = 1; dy = 0; break;
            case 2: dx = -1; dy = 0; break;
        }

        // The next line looks so incredibly ugly…
        Sandstone sandstone = (Sandstone)getOneObjectAtOffset(dx, dy, Sandstone.class);
        if (sandstone != null) {
            getWorld().removeObject(sandstone);
            getWorld().addObject(new Water(), getX() + dx, getY() + dy);
        }

        Sand sand = (Sand)getOneObjectAtOffset(0, 1, Sand.class);
        if (sand != null) {
            ((DoorbraakWorld)getWorld()).stopped = true;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Could I reduce the number of downcasts or is it normal for Java code to contain many downcasts? What else could I improve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Downcasting can usually be avoided by using common methods in abstract types.

```
    if (((DoorbraakWorld)getWorld()).stopped) return;
```

Is this the same as `getWorld().stopped()`?

```
    // The next line looks so incredibly ugly…
    Sandstone sandstone = (Sandstone)getOneObjectAtOffset(dx, dy, Sandstone.class);
    if (sandstone != null) {
        getWorld().removeObject(sandstone);
        getWorld().addObject(new Water(), getX() + dx, getY() + dy);
    }
```

You can use the Actor type: `Actor sandstone = getOneObjectAtOffset(dx, dy, Sandstone.class)`

```
    Sand sand = (Sand)getOneObjectAtOffset(0, 1, Sand.class);
```

Here too: `Actor sand = getOneObjectAtOffset(0, 1, Sand.class);`

```
    ((DoorbraakWorld)getWorld()).stopped = true;
```

How about `greenfoot.stop()`?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you just try removing the casts (one at a time) and seeing if the code still compiles.

- If it does, you've answered your question.
- If it does not, there is probably not much you can do about it ... especially if the root cause is poor API design in a 3rd-party library.

(If `getOneObjectAtOffset` was declared as a generic function, then its declared return type could be the type of the `Class` object, and a downcast wouldn't be necessary.  However: 1) the chances are that you would still require the `Class` parameter, and 2) there would still be a type cast happening behind the scenes when the result is assigned.)

However, there is one place where the cast absolutely cannot be removed:

```
switch ((int)(3.0 * Math.random())) {
```

Without the `(int)` cast, the `switch` would be switching on a `double` value, and that is not legal in Java.  (But I guess, you weren't referring to that cast ... because it is arguably not a "downcast" in the conventional sense.)